# TranslateY does not go beyond a certain boundary in CSS

Tags: html, css

So I was trying to create a landing page in which, when the page loads, the headings of the page come sliding out of the top and sides. I know the basic working but I can't seem to put the headings at a certain position so that when the page loads it comes back to its original position. I have not yet implemented the Javascript but here is the rest of the code::

HTML

```
<body onload="slide()">
 
    <main>
        <section class="landing">
            
                <h1>Find Your Perfect Vacation Point</h1>
                <h3>Let us do the finding for your!</h3>
            

        </section>
    </main>

    


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    
}


.landing{
    background-image: url("bali.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
  
    opacity: .9;

 
}

.heading-container{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    text-align: center;

}


h1{

    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    margin:20px;
    font-size: xx-large;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    transform: translateY(-38%);
    

   
}

h3{

    font-weight: lighter;
    color: white;
    margin:20px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
}
```

Thanks for helping me in advance!!

PS: sorry if i didn't explain my problem very well. It is hard to describe to a problem even if it is a simple one.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [CSS animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp). Here's an example for what you described:

```css
@keyframes slide-from-above {
  from { transform: translate(0, -30px); color: blue }
  to { transform: translate(0, 0); color: red }
}

.nav {
  animation-name: slide-from-above;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav1 {
  animation-delay: 0;
}

#nav2 {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

#nav3 {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

#nav4 {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="nav" id="nav1">Home</div>
  ◆
  <div class="nav" id="nav2">About</div>
  ◆
  <div class="nav" id="nav3">Contact</div>
  ◆
  <div class="nav" id="nav4">Support</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a JS function like below and add an id to your element that should change. Then you can change duration and easing if you want, and it should work. Please say if it is, what you wanted.

I hope I could help you.

If the answer is right, please mark as solved for others. Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='de'>

<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
</head>

<body onload="slide()">

    <main>
        <section class="landing" id="heading">

            <h1>Find Your Perfect Vacation Point</h1>
            <h3>Let us do the finding for your!</h3>

        </section>
    </main>

    <script>
        function slide() {
            div = document.getElementById('heading');
            div.animate(
                [{
                        transform: "translateY(-30px)",
                    },
                    {
                        transform: "translateY(0)",
                    },
                ], {
                    duration: 700,
                    easing: "ease-out",
                    fill: "both",
                }
            );
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this is not what i wanted to accomplish but thanks anways bro. I'll try to figure it out myself

Comment: Then could you describe it better?